# When, exactly, does onLoad occur

Tags: javascript, firefox, onload

I am specifically concerned with the onload event for selected elements of the DOM.  For the purpose of example assume there is an image in my DOM.

As I thought I understood it, the onload event for this image should fire when the image is drawn to the screen, but recently I've been given data to suggest otherwise.  So my question is as follows:

When, in the order of the following events, does the onload event for an image fire?

1. HTML containing the image is examined
2. Request is made for the image
3. First Byte is received for the image
4. Last Byte is received
5. Browser examines the header of the HTTP response
6. Image is drawn to the screen

I am specifically concerned with Firefox, but I would also be interested in how this affects Internet Explorer (specifically IE8) and Chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The load event occurs **after** the image has been drawn on the screen.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/e5hvr/

(The alert blocks the browser thread, so if the image hadn't been drawn already, you wouldn't be able to see it while the alert is still open.)

Comment: So your example is not compelling if the two are run in parallel threads (which I believe IE specifically handles parallel execution for rendering).  So what I did is rig up a screencapture (with timestamps) and record onload events for various components and compare the timestamps to the images.  Now its possible I made a mistake but it seemed to suggest that some images triggered onLoad before being drawn to the screen.

Comment: @tzenes IE has parallel threads for drawing and scripts? I doubt that.

Comment: @tzenes I've tested my demo in FF4, Ch9, O11 and S5, and in all those browsers, the alert popped up cca. 1/2 second after the image appeared on the screen.

Comment: k, then its more than likely the mistake is on my end I'll go back and double check my code.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> While JavaScript provides the load
>   event for executing code when a page
>   is rendered, this event does not get
>   triggered until all assets such as
>   images have been completely received.

So, to answer your question, I would say after all of the events you listed.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting voted down. I know the question doesn't ask about jQuery, but the quote I listed talks about JavaScript, not jQuery. I generally trust jQuery when they talk about JavaScript related matters.

Comment: I ninja down-voted without reading it fully.  Now that I'm less distracted and have read it completely, I've redacted the down-vote (had to edit your answer and add a comma, since my vote was locked in).  (I apologize!)

Comment: Thanks for correcting it Stephen! @Sime I think you might be right :)

Comment: @Stephen Voting and editing are not related. You should be able to retract your vote without having to edit the answer.

Comment: @Šime actually they *are* related.  After a certain amount of time (5 minutes I think), your vote is locked in and cannot be changed unless the answer is edited.  Try it out, go to something you voted on earlier today and try to remove the vote.

Comment: @Stephen Ah yes, I didn't know that. This rule is kind-of silly though since users with enough reputation can simply edit the post (make some insignificant change) and retract the vote afterwards.

Comment: @Jeff This quote is ambiguous  On the one hand it says "page is rendered", on the other hand it also says "images have been completely received."  In the case of a single image these are two different events (last byte and rendered), and what I'm trying to parse is which of these is relevant.

Comment: @tzenes You're arguing semantics. If you really want to get wordy, the page can be rendered before it even leaves the server (.NET even has a OnRender event) or it could be "rendered" when the browser receives the first byte. These definitions as well as yours are not what this passage is referring to. I suppose there is a better wording out there but I think this is clear enough.

Comment: @Jeff I'm not trying to argue I'm trying to understand.  This statement is ambiguous and I don't understand it.  Here I'm asking for clarification.  What does "rendered" mean here?

Comment: @tzenes apologies then. in context, these docs are saying that rendering happens after page load. however, i would shy away from using "rendering" as a term because I have never heard it used in JS documentation and as this discussion is proving, it is an unclear issue. the important part of that passage is after the comma. i suppose in that sense, i am agreeing with you now. i dont know how you did it but you got me to argue for your position without even saying anything :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say all but 6. And your events are in the wrong order, of course; the headers come before the data.

Comment: Depends on what you consider first byte.  You might consider first bytes to bet the first http byte, in which case you get first byte before headers.  Its also possible that the time stamp for first byte is also last byte, in which case both come before examining headers.  The order of those events are non-deterministic

Comment: @tzenes well, he does say the first byte of the image, rather than the http response, but point taken about receiving the first packet before examining the headers (assuming they fit in a packet...)